# Error in Creating Class prototype

Tags: c++

Can anyone help me?
I want to create 2 classes which need each other like:

```
class CBullet{
  public:
         bool DetectCollision(CEnemy enemy){
              //some code here
         }
};
```

and

```
class CEnemy{
  public:
         CBullet *shootedBullet;
};
```

this creating an error. I know the reason for this error is because `CBullet` class want to use `CEnemy` class which is not created yet. So, i try to create a prototype of `CEnemy` class before `CBullet` class like:

```
class CEnemy;

class CBullet{
...
```

but it create another error `enemy` has incomplete type.
Did I make a wrong prototype class?

Answer (score 0):

Do it the other way, as in your example CBullet needs CEnemy definition (note that it wouldn't if Cenemy would have been passed by pointer/reference to DetectCollision) :

```
#include "CEnemy.h"
class CBullet{
  public:
         bool DetectCollision(CEnemy enemy){
              //some code here
         }
};

and

class CBullet;
class CEnemy{
  public:
         CBullet *shootedBullet;
};
```